# In the given figure, $PQRS$

Tags: geometry

In the given figure, $PQRS$ is a parallelogram. Prove that $\triangle RQN=\triangle MNS$
[image]

My Attempt

1$$\triangle PMS=\frac {1}{2} Parallelogram PQRS$$

$$\triangle PQM +\triangle RMS=\frac {1}{2} parallelogram PQRS$$

$$\triangle PMS=\triangle PQM + \triangle RMS$$

Now, what should I do next?

Comment: $M$ is any point on $QR$? Or something like the midpoint?

Comment: It hasn't been specified

Comment: Yeah the condition hasn't been provided

Comment: I don't think it is true if no other conditions are given. However, it's just my idea. It might be true, but I fail to see how it might be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H$ and $K$ be the perpendicular projections of $P$ and $N$ onto the line $QR$. Since $\triangle PQM$ and $\triangle NMR$ are similar, 
$$\frac{PH}{NK}=\frac{QM}{MR}.$$
It follows that
$$\frac{area(\triangle PQM)}{area(\triangle QMN)}=\frac{PH\cdot QM}{NK\cdot QM} =\frac{QM}{MR}.$$
It is also obvious that 
$$\frac{area(\triangle PQM)}{area(\triangle SMR)}=\frac{QM}{MR}.$$
Thus, $area(\triangle QMN) = area(\triangle SMR)$.

Comment: How is $\triangle PQM$ and $\triangle MNR$ similar?  Could you please explain?